# What is the term to describe the keywords let, const and var?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, terminology

When teaching, it helps to have a common set of terms to describe categories of things to facilitate comprehension. Before let and const, I could just call var, "the var keyword"...

Now we have 3 keywords that are used to declare a variable: var, let and const.

I've done a few searches and still can't find an answer: Is there a categorical name to describe these three keywords separately from any other?

Thanks all!

Comment: MDN uses *statement* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/let

Comment: All three are `variable declarations`.

Comment: `declarations` https://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/6.0/#sec-declarations-and-the-variable-statement

Comment: And the more formal term for "variables" is *bindings* (think of a value being bound to a "label").

Answer (score 5, accepted):

They are each the first token of a declaration statement, so you could call them "declaration keywords".

However, it's worth noting that `let` is not actually a keyword at all. EG.

```js
var let = 5;
console.log( let );
```

is perfectly valid outside strict-mode, but since `const` and `var` are keywords, these are not allowed:

```js
var const = 5;
var var = 5;
```

Comment: I like "declaration keywords", though I hoped there might be a single word to describe them. Perhaps something like "declarators". Also, let is definitely a keyword in ES2015 terms, but interesting to note that it isn't considered a reserved word. Thanks for your input.

Comment: All keywords are reserved words. The set of reserved words is a superset of the set of keywords. There are some reserved words that are not keywords, EG. `null`, `true`, `false`, `enum`, and many more in strict-mode, and some identifiers that are treated like reserved words in strict-mode but are not actually reserved words (or keywords), including `let`.

Comment: @JamesMarks The spec identifiers three types of "Declaration": ClassDeclaration `class`, HoistableDeclaration `function` (including async and generator declarations) and `var`, and LexicalDeclaration (`let` and `const`). You may want to mentally classify all of those as "declarators", even if you are not teaching all of them. I don't see a reason to tell a student the complete list of declarators unless they ask if there are others, just the ones they are learning about.

Comment: Interesting. The idea that let has a functional purpose that is otherwise indistinguishable from var and const, but is not technically considered a "keyword" is a little strange, but I guess it is what it is. As for adding class and function to the list, that makes sense. Thanks again.

Comment: Just out of curiosity, do you know of a resource that I can read that will help clarify the definition of a keyword in the context of javascript? Now I feel like I'm missing some potentially important information :)

Comment: @JamesMarks I don't have a good resource, but I can clarify; although I'm kind of making an educated guess here: JavaScript uses a different definition of "keyword" from most language. When talking about another language `let` would be a keyword because it has semantic meaning. JavaScript on the other hand has a well-defined list of what is a keyword which ideally ***should*** include all words that have semantic meaning, but doesn't, which I believe is for backwards compatibility reasons. This is why they have the concept of "future reserved words".

Comment: JavaScript tends to be extra strict with backwards compatibility even across major versions, because valid code that works in a browser should not break when the browser updates. So if a word was not originally a "future reserved word" they can't give it semantics without a lot of workarounds which is what they did for `let`. They didn't want to break that one guy's code that had `var let = 5;` in it, so they chose to keep it out of the list of keywords, and only make it invalid in new contexts that weren't valid in the old version of the language anyway (`const let = 5;` is not valid).

Comment: That's also why they introduced "strict" mode instead of just updating the language. They could remove deprecated features and they could reserve more words for the future, like `"private"`, `"public"`, `"implements"`, etc that were not already reserved before strict mode was created; and still avoiding breaking old code that used those as identifiers (since the old code would not have `"use strict";`).

Comment: `const` was always a reserved word (at least since ES3, I didn't check earlier version) classified as a "future reserved word", so they were able to make it a keyword because `var const = 5;` was always invalid.